# Waiting for the debugger to disconnect... Node.js in VSCode

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I can't solve the problem always getting connection problem.
**Debugger attached.
DB conneciton failed{
"code": "ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR",
"errno": 1045,
"sqlMessage": "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)",
"sqlState": "28000",
"fatal": true
}
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...**

[image: mark appearing in my code]

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "data-sign-up",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1"
  }
}
```

index.js:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');


var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '1234',
    database: 'EmployeeDB'

});

mysqlConnection.connect((err)=>{
    if(!err)
    console.log("DB connection succeded.")
    else
    console.log('DB conneciton failed'+ JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete launch.json generated by vs code then closes and starts your vs code again. I got my problem fixed